# Making the wordpress login form a jQuery dropdown

Tags: jquery, login, forms, wp-login-form

I'm using a plugin called `sidebar-login` to display a wordpress login form (it uses `wp_login_form`) in my sidebar. However, I feel like it the actual form (textboxes and labels) take up too much space and I'd like to hide it all in a slide-down jQuery div.

Basically, the user would click on a link called `"Login"`, which would make the login form fade in and slide down for the user to use. The problem is I need to add that link and wrap up the whole form in a div that I can apply a jQuery rule to.

What is the recommended way of doing this so I don't break any existing login procedures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [SimpleModal Login](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-login/). This should be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I just downloaded and tried this out, it works exactly like what I want. The only thing is that it still says "Login" or "Register" even if a user is logged in. I'm going to need to modify the actual plugin (instead of just using a widget) because I need PHP. Cheers

Comment: you can also add the link in php - it is the usual `wp_loginout()` function, and works with the plugin.